# Expanding and Collapsing Sidebars?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a sidebar and can get it to expand with a button press, but don't know how to make it collapse with the same button. In addition to this, the action repeats itself when you go to another tab and return to the website. If someone could help with this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.
[1st Part of CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLR2J.png) | [2nd Part of CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hynd.png)

```css
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 1303px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: ease-out 0.5s;
  background-image: url('/Images/Menu_Icon.png');
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links {
  font-family: 'comfortaa';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
}

.links:hover {
  color: #5e00bc;
}

.linkList {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -150px;
  top: 85px;
  transition: ease-out 0.5s;
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

.linkList ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menuButton:focus~.linkList {
  right: 0px;
}

.linkList:hover {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu'>
  <button class='menuButton'></button>
  <div class='linkList'>
    <ul>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 6</a></li>
      <li><a class='links' href='#'>Link 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a code snippet: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or perhaps a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net so people can see your entire code. It is hard to draw much from two screenshots of your CSS.

Comment: This is nice, but I also can’t help with a solution unless I see the full code. Is this project in a github repo?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  The question as written lacks sufficient detail for specific guidance to be provided to you.  Generally you should include an [mcve] **as text** in the body of the question, any steps to reproduce, the expected result, and the actual result.  Sometimes an image of the outcome might be helpful as well.  Critically, [**please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @Pufferfishe - your heart is certainly in the right place, but a link to the question-asker's source code would be an instance of [linking to the problem offsite, which is generally forbidden/bad practice on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @AlexanderNied I understand - I just figured that OP wouldn’t want to copy and paste code, because they didn’t in the first place, so I thought a repo link would be a good idea. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I just didn't know how to put code on here lol. I'm new to this site

Comment: @V4N464NDR This code snippet you just provided does not show anything when run - please be sure to provide your ENTIRE code, or at least all the code that can reproduce this example. The latter can be small.

Comment: It is the full code. You have to move the bottom scroll bar all the way over since the bar is coded to be on the right side. (or you could open a full page of the result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

```js
menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("menuButton")[0];
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menu = document.getElementsByClassName("linkList")[0];
  menu.style.webkitTransition = "0.5s";
  if (menu.style.right == "0px") {
    menu.style.right = "-100%";
  } else {
    menu.style.right = "0px";
  }
});
```

```css
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 1303px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-image: url("/Images/Menu_Icon.png");
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links {
  font-family: "comfortaa";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.links:hover {
  color: #5e00bc;
}

.linkList {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  right: -150px;
  top: 85px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

.linkList ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.linkList:hover {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button class="menuButton"></button>
  <div class="linkList">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
      <li><a class="links" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added JS code to handle Click event.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I was trying to figure this out for days!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [jQuery's `animate` function](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) with [jQuery UI's `easing` options](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) instead of CSS transitions. It is more configurable and is less likely to break when you add new stuff to your page. Try this code, using Javascript and [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```html
<body>
    <!-- add the jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- add the jQuery UI library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div class = 'menu'>
        <button class = 'menuButton'></button>
        <div class = 'linkList'>
            <ul>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a class = 'links' href = '#'>Link 7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <style>
            .menuButton {
                position: absolute;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                top: 25px;
                left: 1303px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                background-image: url('/Images/Menu_Icon.png');
                background-color: #e0e0e0;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .links {
                font-family: 'comfortaa';
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 500;
                color: #000000;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .links:hover {
                color: #5e00bc;
            }

            .linkList {
                position: fixed;
                width: 150px;
                height: 100%;
                right: -150px;
                top: 85px;
                background: #e0e0e0;
            }

            .linkList ul li {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            
        </style>
        <script>
            // this block of code will run every time the user clicks on the element with the menuButton class
            document.getElementsByClassName('menuButton')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
                // if the menu is visible
                if ($('.linkList').hasClass('visible')) {
                    // slide to the left out of sight, and remove the 'visible' class
                    $('.linkList').animate({"right": "-150px"}, 500, "easeOutQuart").removeClass('visible');

                // if the menu is not visible
                } else if (!$('.linkList').hasClass('visible')) {
                    // slide to the right into sight, and add the 'visible' class
                    $('.linkList').animate({"right": "0px"}, 500, "easeOutQuart").addClass('visible');
                }
            })
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```